# Calculating time of simulation

Tags: matlab

I am doing simulations for

```
time step = 1.0 e^-7  &
total number of steps ==> nsteps = 1.0 e^8
```

I have to find the total time of simulation at which n# steps is achieved. 
Is it ok to multiply both to get the time of simulation?

```
time of simulation = time step * total number of steps
time of simulation =   1.0 e^-7 * 1.0 e^8
time of simulation =  10
```

Is this right or wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a yes/no question, so:

**No, (or yes, depending on how accurately you want the answer to be)!**

But you are really close... You need to subtract one `time_step`, thus the answer is really:

```
time_of_simulation = time_step * total_number_of_steps - time_step;
```

You will see the reason if you consider counting seconds. Start with a number and see how far you get if you count one second at a time.

1, 2, 3 => Three measurements, but only 2 seconds.

However, in your case, I guess you are close enough without the last subtraction, because

```
time of simulation = 9.999999 is pretty close to 10
```